# is it possible to access other users passes from wallet app in ios

Tags: ios, passkit

I want to use passes of other iPhone user from its wallet app.

Example : when user1 wants to use user2's card, user 1 will send message to user2 via our ap (message from user 1: user2 please release payment for $x)

user 2 receives this message and then simply accesses passport via our app.. Chooses the card and send that card pass to user1 for 10 minutes to use on via their passport.

Is this possible to access ?

Comment: I hope not, can you imagine if you could access by wallet via code and get all my cards! That would be a huge security and privacy issue. You can only add new cards/tickets to the wallet and lets keep it that way.

Comment: yeah that is my concern too, but we can share our card with others via Wallet app ios native app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible, every pass is signed with entitlements. Passes that you do not have the entitlements to will not returned.

[PKPassLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPassLibrary_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PKPassLibrary/passes) passes methods in the documentation:

> Your app only has access to certain passes, based on its entitlements.
>   Passes that your app doesn’t have access to are not returned.